# Send InkCanvas strokes directly to IRandomnaccessStream

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to get a byte array from the `InkCanvas` control, but the method i've come up with so far seems a bit long winded.

Currently I use the following:

```
StorageFolder folder = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFolderAsync("Temp");
StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(GenerateString(5)+".zzx", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    await SignatureCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.SaveAsync(stream);                        
    var array = await IRandomAccessStreamToByteArray(stream);                 
}
```

The custom stream reader is as follows.

```
private async Task<byte[]> IRandomAccessStreamToByteArray(IRandomAccessStream stream)
{
    var reader = new DataReader(stream.GetInputStreamAt(0));
    var bytes = new byte[stream.Size];
    await reader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
    reader.ReadBytes(bytes);
    return bytes;
}
```

This works, and gives me the byte array that i need, but also leaves me with unwanted images. Was having some access issues due to files still being written when another call wanted to replace the file so decided to go down the multiple images route. Is there a way to skip the image file entirely? It's not too much of an issue to clear out a temp folder, but if it can be avoided that would be preferable.

I had read somewhere already that InkCanvas doesn't support direct to array dumps, so any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: You should be able to use the same file to save the `IRandomAccessStream` and use it to get the byte array.

Comment: @JaydenGu-MSFT The code above does indeed generate the file, however the file itself isn't used (instead i pinch the newly written stream data and convert that). What im looking for is a way to remove that "create a file" middle step (if it is even possible)

Comment: Any updates? Did my answer solve you problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save your `InkCanvas` strokes to bytes Array without create the file, you should be able to use the `Win2D.uwp`.

To install `Win2D.uwp`, run the "Install-Package Win2D.uwp" command in the Package Manager Console.

There is a `CanvasDrawingSession.DrawInk` method to draw a collection of ink strokes. That we should be able to use `CanvasBitmap.GetPixelBytes` method to get an array of raw byte data for the entire bitmap.

For example:

```
private byte[] ConvertInkCanvasToByteArray()
{
    var canvasStrokes = SignatureCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.GetStrokes();
    if (canvasStrokes.Count > 0)
    {
        var width = (int)SignatureCanvas.ActualWidth;
        var height = (int)SignatureCanvas.ActualHeight;
        var device = CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice();
        device.DeviceLost += DeviceOnDeviceLost;
        var renderTarget = new CanvasRenderTarget(device, width, height, 96);
        using (var ds = renderTarget.CreateDrawingSession())
        {
            ds.Clear(Windows.UI.Colors.White);
            ds.DrawInk(SignatureCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.GetStrokes());
        }
        return renderTarget.GetPixelBytes();
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}

private void DeviceOnDeviceLost(CanvasDevice sender, object args)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("DeviceOnDeviceLost");
}
```

Also if we want to convert the bytes array to image, we should be able to use following code:

```
WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)SignatureCanvas.ActualWidth, (int)SignatureCanvas.ActualHeight);
await bitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream().WriteAsync(mybytes, 0, mybytes.Length);
```